# Create dictionary from user input after user determines number of entries (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm asking the user to enter input, which the program is storing in a dictionary (code below).  I need to ask the user how many entries exist first, and count them as they enter.  I've used counts but do not know how to implement a user defined count limit.

```
entriesDict = {}

while True:
    x = input('Please enter the name: ')
    y = input('Please enter their score: ')
    if x == '':
        break
    entriesDict[x] = y
print(entriesDict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first get user input once to determine the number of entries. Then, use a for loop to get an entry repeatedly.

```
entriesDict = {}

num_entries = input('Please enter the number of entries: ')

for i in range(num_entries):
    x = input('Please enter the name: ')
    y = input('Please enter their score: ')
    entriesDict[i] = y
print(entriesDict)
```

Comment: I understand! Thank you, I didn't think to use a for-loop and set a range with the number of entries.  I would upvote if I had the reps.